# Oracle compiler and stored constants in index

Tags: oracle, indexing, sql-execution-plan

Lets say I have objects below and I want to create procedure with query that uses my_index. I tried to use explain plan window inside my plsql developer (I had to strip just the query out of the block) and It seemed that select in variant A converted my_constant to variable and my_index was not used. If I generated explain plan for query in variant B, my_index was used. Is it really so that I have to use variant B for my_index to work?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package IS
  my_constant CONSTANT NUMBER(1) := 1;
END;

CREATE TABLE my_table (my_id NUMBER,my_column NUMBER(1));

CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (CASE WHEN my_column = 1 THEN my_id END);

-- variant A (using my_constant directly)
DECLARE
  v_my_id my_table.my_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT my_id
    INTO v_my_id
    FROM my_table
   WHERE CASE
           WHEN my_column = my_package.my_constant THEN
            my_id
         END = 123;
END;

-- variant B (using value of constant with commented refference for future me)
DECLARE
  v_my_id my_table.my_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT my_id
    INTO v_my_id
    FROM my_table
   WHERE CASE
           WHEN my_column = 1 /*my_package.my_constant*/ THEN
            my_id
         END = 123;
END;
```

I tried to search the forums, asked my DBA, chat GPT and I was not still able to find the satisfying answer..

Comment: Your index will not work as there is no `my_id` column in the table.

Comment: It has now. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PL/SQL package variables directly in the SQL scope; however, you can use PL/SQL functions in the SQL scope and write a wrapper for the constant:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package IS
  my_constant CONSTANT NUMBER(1) := 1;

  FUNCTION get_my_constant RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package IS
  FUNCTION get_my_constant RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN my_constant;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT my_id
FROM   my_table
WHERE  CASE WHEN my_column = my_package.get_my_constant() THEN my_id END = 123;
```

You can use PL/SQL package variables in the PL/SQL scope and pass them as bind variables to an SQL query:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_my_id my_table.my_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT my_id
  INTO   v_my_id
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE CASE WHEN my_column = my_package.my_constant THEN my_id END = 123;
END;
/
```

However, in both these cases, the SQL engine does not know that the value is a constant in the PL/SQL scope and has to treat it as a variable and then it does not know that the value will always be 1 so the index will not be used.

---

What you can do is create the index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX my_index2 ON my_table (my_column, my_id);
```

And then use:

```sql
SELECT my_id
FROM   my_table
WHERE  my_column = my_package.get_my_constant()
AND    my_id = 123;
```

Which can use the index.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2RZZQBgx) for examples and explain plans.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think you stopped half way through. I played with .. the fiddle.. and if I created index like that `CREATE INDEX my_index3 ON my_table (case when my_column = my_package.get_my_constant() THEN my_id END);` the compliler used the index as expected.

Comment: @MrGoodman You could add that as a self-answer to the question.